# Positive integers $<100000$, how many contain exactly one $3$, one $4$ and one $5$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

So I use $5$ positions for range $00000$ to $99999$

Choose $3$, choose $4$ and choose $5$ as follows:

$5C1 \cdot 4C1 \cdot 3C1$

Remaining $2$ digits have $7$ possible digits as input
Ans: $5C1 \cdot 4C1 \cdot 3C1 \cdot 7 \cdot 7$.

My question is, what if the question asks contain exactly one $3$ OR one $4$ OR one $5$?

Let $A$ be the set which contains a number with a single $3$.
Let $B$ be the set which contains a number with a single $4$.
Let $C$ be the set which contains a number with a single $5$.

$|A| = (9^4) \cdot 5$

$|B| = (9^4) \cdot 5$

$|C| = (9^4) \cdot 5$

$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$

How do I proceed?

My further attempt:

$|A \cap B| = 5C1 \cdot 4C1 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 = 10240$

$|A \cap B| = |A \cap C| = |B \cap C| = 10240$

$|A \cap B \cap C| = 5C1 \cdot 4C1 \cdot 3C1 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 = 2940$

Answer $= 32805 + 32805 + 32805 - 10240 - 10240 - 10240 + 2940 = 70635$

Comment: Be careful, numbers should not begin with a 0.

Comment: @almagest I don't think that's a problem. The OP didn't say it had to be a $5$ digit number.

Comment: And to the OP, why don't you just calculate all those?

Comment: Hi is my edit correct?

Comment: But the heading implies no leading zeros.

Comment: Leading zeroes are allowed

Comment: @almagest How exactly?

Comment: @RStyle Why did you roll back the edit? Mathjax was better.

Comment: Oops i think iwas editing halfway lol

Comment: @SayantanSantra Because it says "Positive integers less than ..." instead of "5 digit sequences".

Comment: @RStyle Anyways, I think you got this. Your "further attempt" seems sound.

Comment: @almagest Yeah, but how is $00001$ different from $1$ in this context? That's an unique representation.

Comment: @SayantanSantra Good point!